# How to get a list of options, that can pushed to the clients?

Tags: openvpn

The OpenVPN manual currently only states:

> This is a partial list of options which can currently be pushed: --route, --route-gateway, --route-delay, --redirect-gateway, --ip-win32, --dhcp-option, --inactive, --ping, --ping-exit, --ping-restart, --setenv, --persist-key, --persist-tun, --echo, --comp-lzo, --socket-flags, --sndbuf, --rcvbuf

But how do I get a complete list of options I can push to clients?

Answer (score 2):

The generic way is to look through the code.

The method `pull_permission_mask` of [init.c](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/master/src/openvpn/init.c) contains a list of valid flags (cited here for the current 2.3 release):

```
unsigned int flags =
      OPT_P_UP
    | OPT_P_ROUTE_EXTRAS
    | OPT_P_SOCKBUF
    | OPT_P_SOCKFLAGS
    | OPT_P_SETENV
    | OPT_P_SHAPER
    | OPT_P_TIMER
    | OPT_P_COMP
    | OPT_P_PERSIST
    | OPT_P_MESSAGES
    | OPT_P_EXPLICIT_NOTIFY
    | OPT_P_ECHO
    | OPT_P_PULL_MODE
    | OPT_P_PEER_ID;
```

If `--route-nopull` is not set on client-side, the following flags are currently accepted additionally:

```
flags |= (OPT_P_ROUTE | OPT_P_IPWIN32);
```

Now we have to match this against the options from [options.c](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/master/src/openvpn/options.c).
Each option, that has one of the flags above in its `VERIFY_PERMISSION` can theoretically be pushed to the client. of course there could be issues [as with comp-lzo](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/128).

As an example see the following snippet from options.c:

```
else if (streq (p[0], "topology") && p[1])
    {
      VERIFY_PERMISSION (OPT_P_UP);
      options->topology = parse_topology (p[1], msglevel);
    }
```

Since `OPT_P_UP` is in the list of flags above, "topology" may be pushed to clients.